# Última vez que un usuario cerro sesión en django 1.9

Tags: django

Mi inquietud es que si hay alguna forma de ver la ultima vez que un usuario cerro sesión, quizás como la de `last_login`. Fecha y hora de la última vez que el usuario se identificó, pero en este caso no tengo ninguna idea de cómo hacer para mostrar la última vez que el usuario haya cerrado sesión.

Answer (score 3):

Una forma simple sería usar las señales que tiene Django por defecto, la señal `user_logged_out` se lanza cuando el usuario cierra la sesión, con esto ya podrías guardar la fecha y hora en un campo de tu modelo User o en algún otro.

Mas info aquí:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/auth/#topics-auth-signals

Answer (score 2):

Pues ese campo no existe por defecto, las únicas fechas que se guardan relacionadas al usuario de Django son la fecha en que se unió y la última fecha en que inició sesión (`date_joined` y `last_login` respectivamente).

Una opcíon es que [extiendas el usuario](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) con un modelo tipo Perfil pero lo que te recomendaría es usar la librería llamada [`django-axes`](https://github.com/django-pci/django-axes) que yo la utilizo para conocer los intentos fallidos de inicio de sesión pero que aparte de eso guarda en una tabla llamada `axes_accesslog` los registros del momento en el que un usuario inició la sesión (`attempt_time`) y también el momento en el que cerró la sesión (`logout_time`).

Para instalarla:

```
$ pip install django-axes
```

Estas son todas las opciones que puedes usar para configurar `django-axes` en tu `settings.py` (tal vez no las necesites todas):

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
   ...
    'axes',
    ...
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'axes.middleware.FailedLoginMiddleware'
)

# Axes
AXES_LOGIN_FAILURE_LIMIT = 3
AXES_LOCK_OUT_AT_FAILURE = True
AXES_USE_USER_AGENT = False
AXES_COOLOFF_TIME = None
AXES_LOGGER = 'axes.watch_login'
AXES_LOCKOUT_TEMPLATE = 'lockout.html'
AXES_LOCKOUT_URL = None
AXES_VERBOSE = True
AXES_USERNAME_FORM_FIELD = 'username'
AXES_LOCK_OUT_BY_COMBINATION_USER_AND_IP = True
```

Luego para obtener, por ejemplo, el momento que cerro sesión el usuario `cesar` puedes hacer algo como:

```
>>> from axes.models import AccesLog
>>> access_log = AccessLog.objects.filter(username='cesar', trusted=True).latest('logout_time')
>>> access_log.logout_time
datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 11, 16, 2, 49, 924312)
```

Estoy usando solo aquellos registros con `trusted=True` ya que no nos interesan los intentos de sesión fallidos. También, puede que necesites validar la existencia del registro.